# PHP PhantomJS - Not found on hosted server

Tags: php

I am trying to get PhantomJS to work on a hosted server. I downloaded the latest binary from the website and uploaded via FTP to the server.

Here is the code, I am running from the browser.

```
<?php 
      putenv('PATH=phantomjs');
      include("scrapper.php");
      $cssSelector = "table.temp";
      $siteUrl = "www.website.com";
      $tableXmlObject = pullXmlObjBlogExample($siteUrl,$cssSelector);
      $cnt = 0;
      print_r($tableXmlObject);
?>
```

I put the `phantomjs` file in the same folder as this script. I get this error:

```
sh: 1: phantomjs: not found
```

Comment: Did you just upload the executable file, I'm pretty sure that won't install it. What have you tried? What trouble shooting steps have you taken? Did you read their documentation? Try taking a look at this: https://www.joecolantonio.com/2014/10/14/how-to-install-phantomjs/